# React native (axios) not able to send request to backend server on localhost/ip address

Tags: rest, react-native, localhost, ios-simulator, axios

I am running an app in Iphone simulator using `yarn ios` with **Expo**. There is a request in my apiMiddleware and it tries to connect to my backend server that runs on http://localhost:8080.

However, I got this error after trying to connect both **localhost:8080** and **192.168.0.3:8080** where **192.168.0.3** is my Mac IPv4 Address:

```
Request failed with status code 404
- node_modules/axios-mock-adapter/src/utils.js:117:24 in createErrorResponse
- node_modules/axios-mock-adapter/src/utils.js:98:8 in settle
```

Both Chrome browser and Insomnia can send requests and get responses from **localhost:8080** or **192.168.0.3:8080**.

I went through several posts and solutions are to change localhost to ip address, which doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try Ngrok https://ngrok.com/

Comment: @ShabbirHaider Thanks for reply and I tried ngrok. Looks like it is a problem the app cannot send request to neither public domain nor localhost. I still don't have a solution for this.